# Is there a difference in time based goals and achievement goals?

Tags: emotion, study-cognitive-sciences, goals

Suppose I want to practice my calculus. Has a study been conducted which shows a difference between setting a goal like: '*I will study calculus for one hour*' and '*I will study chapter 3 from my calculus textbook*' in terms of completion?

Does one method have a higher failure rate than the other? Does one have a higher chance to begin the task?